# IE Extension using VC++

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++

Trying to develop an IE Toolbar extension using VC++ (ATL) to type in the username and password based on a custom event. Not sure how can the extension code listen for a custom event.

I want to create and fire an event LaunchURL (something like below)and handle it in the extension code.

```
var t = document.createEvent("Event");
t.initEvent("LaunchURL", true, true);
document.dispatchEvent(t);
```

Looking for some pointers to achieve this. Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks in advance,
Shan

Comment: show what you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Custom event() is not supported in IE so you need to use polyfill for it. Here you can see.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent I try to find the way to capture the custom event from BHO IE extension but did not get any useful information on that.